# kops k8s cluster Kubectl commands Timeout issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kops

I was trying to run 
"`kubectl get nodes`" command for k8s cluster.it gives "Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp..."
this is a k8s cluster created by a different user in the company AWS account.
this is the steps I have followed

```
export AWS_PROFILE=RR
export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://s3bucketname 
kops export kubecfg dev.k8s.local
kubectl config get-contexts      

kubectl get nodes                                                                                                                                                              12:53:18 
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 3.136.226.173:443: i/o timeout
```

I need to view running nodes and services in this k8 cluster how can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Possible cause one: routing/firewall issues

It happens when you create/use private cluster.

To solve - add an external `IP` to authorized networks.

to get your external `IP` address, you can use some of [these commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81699/145897):

```
curl ifconfig.co
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com

curl ifconfig.me
curl ifconfig.co
curl smart-ip.net/myip
wget -O - -q icanhazip.com
wget -O - -q ifconfig.me/ip
```

Other such resources:

- http://ip.tyk.nu/
- http://whatismyip.akamai.com/
- http://tnx.nl/ip
- http://ifcfg.me/
- http://l2.io/ip
- http://ip.appspot.com/
- http://ident.me/
- http://ipof.in/txt
- http://icanhazip.com/
- http://curlmyip.com/
- http://wgetip.com/
- http://curlmyip.com/
- http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/
- http://eth0.me/
- http://ifconfig.me/
- http://corz.org/ip
- http://ipecho.net/plain

### Possible cause two: lost/stale `k8s` context

To get context use:

```
kubectl config view
```

To set context use:

```
kubectl config set-context <your_context>
```

### Possible cause three: outdated CF template

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54877219/5720818), you'd check an `AMI` template that used when cluster was created.

> The cluster was set up using an older version of the CloudFormation template